# Setting value with `textarea.value("")` throws “`TypeError`: `textarea.value` is not a function”

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I’m trying to set the `value` of the `<textarea>` (`planned_use_select.nextSibling`) to an empty string.

```js
var planned_use_select = document.querySelector("select[name=planned_use]");

planned_use_select.addEventListener("change", function() {
  planned_use_select.nextSibling.setAttribute("class", "hidden");
  planned_use_select.nextSibling.value("");
});
```

```html
<div class="form-input">
  <select name="planned_use">
    <option value="Foo">foo</option>
    <option value="Bar">bar</option>
    <option value="Other">Something else</option>
  </select>
  <textarea class="other_planned_use" name="other_planned_use" placeholder="We'd love to know more!"></textarea>
</div>
```

The first line works fine (correctly applies the class and hides the textarea) but the second line fails: it produces this error:

```
index.js:200 Uncaught TypeError: planned_use_select.nextSibling.value 
is not a function
at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (index.js:200)
```

Why can I use `.setAttribute()` but not `.value()`?

Comment: because value is a property, not a function

Comment: The error is actually pretty clear. Value is not a function.

Comment: `value` is generally not a function property of any HTML DOM element, so this question is also applicable to `<input>`, `<param>`, `<option>`, `<output>`, `<data>`, `<select>`, `<button>`, `<li>`, `<meter>`, and `<progress>` elements, in addition to `<textarea>`s: those are all HTML elements (as of HTML5 in 2021) which have some kind of `value` property. The confusion may stem from jQuery which has a `.val` method, in contrast to the native DOM API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `planned_use_select.nextSibling.value = ""`

`value` is a property which you can get or set. It is not a function.